# Lauching pgsql2shp request on server by user

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I am running PostgreSQL 9.4 and PostGIS 2.3.

I use Python scripting to launch a connexion to PostgreSQL with psycopg2.

My script is about the export of some queries in shapefile. Everything works fine when I launch it from my Windows session (I am administrator on the server), but when I try to launch it from another session I get an "Access denied" message. I am guessing it is linked with the fact that this other session isn't administrator.

I don't know much about systems, so I am guessing more informations are needed to help me solve that, but would anyone have an idea on where lies the problem and how to solve it? Obviously defining all my users as administrators is not an option.

Here is a sample of how my scripts look like (I connect through SSPI so don't need any user/password):

```
os.environ['PATH'] += r';SET PGCLIENTENCODING=LATIN1;S:\\ProgCommun'
os.environ['PGHOST'] = '10.159.107.13'
os.environ['PGPORT'] = '5432'
os.environ['PGDATABASE'] = 'SIEA'

cmds = '''"\\\\10.159.107.12\\xxx\\pgsql2shp.exe" -f "{}" -g geom DABASE "select * from table" '''
cmds = cmds.format(fichier)
subprocess.call(cmds, shell=True)
```

The IP are different since I try to use a local version of the pgsql2shp (and in so doing try to avoid executing anything on the server). But it doesn't work either way...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution, it was due to a lack of DLL files in the directory where I put the pgsql2shp.exe file...